# Looping until the health runs out - Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal, command-line-interface

I am creating a JS CLI Game.

I need a loop that will automatically decrease health on both the player and the enemy and it won't stop until one of their's healths becomes 0 or less.

```js
while (playerHealth > 0 || enemyHealth > 0) {
      if (playerHealth > 0 || enemyHealth > 0) {
        headerColor("Round", colors.blue, colors.green)

        let decreaseHealth1 = randomDecreaseHealth()
        playerHealth - decreaseHealth1
        console.log("Ouch ! You lost " + decreaseHealth1)

        let decreaseHealth2 = randomDecreaseHealth()
        enemyHealth - decreaseHealth2
        console.log("Nice hit. Enemy lost " + decreaseHealth2)
      } else if (playerHealth <= 0) {
        console.log("Damn, you lost.  ")
      } else if (enemyHealth <= 0) {
        console.log("Yayyyyy, YOU WONNN !!! ")
      }
    }
```

This creates an infinite loop.

The `headerColor("Round", colors.blue, colors.green)` function creates a header that looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCWes.png

`randomDecreaseHealth()` generates a random number that is used to decrease health from both the player and the enemy. I need different numbers. It doesn't always decrease the same amount. So normally I'd just call the function, except that I need to display the number by which health was decreased, so I stored it in a variable so that I could display that number.

So, basically, I need this loop to goes on until either `playerHealth` either `enemyHealth` reaches 0 or less. Also, I need that at the start of each round, the header displays the number of the round next to the *Round* word. One round is consisted of one hit taken and one hit given.

Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `playerHealth - decreaseHealth1` doesn't assign a new value. You need `playerHealth -= decreaseHealth1` to actually decrease the value. See [Subtraction assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Subtraction_assignment) for more info

Comment: Yeah, I just saw the error. Thanks. However that doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Because nodejs is event driven, you don't generally do a `while()` loop for your main program execution because other events won't be able to run.  Technically, you can if there is at least one  `await` in the loop, but that's not usually how you write things in nodejs.  More commonly, you would set up things that create events.  Perhaps you use a timer to decrease the health, every xxx ms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.
Because I imported `playerHealth` variable, for some unknown reason it was considered as a constant (even though I exported it as `let`). That's why it returned the error: *TypeError: Assignment to constant variable*. So I stored the imported `playerHealth` variable in another local variable and that solved the problem.

```js
  let count = 0
  let playerHealthFight = playerHealth


function hit() {
    if (playerHealthFight > 0 && enemyHealth > 0) {
      count++

      headerColor("Round #" + count, colors.green, colors.blue)

      let decreaseHealth1 = randomDecreaseHealth()
      playerHealthFight -= decreaseHealth1
      console.log("Ouch ! You lost " + decreaseHealth1)

      let decreaseHealth2 = randomDecreaseHealth()
      enemyHealth -= decreaseHealth2
      console.log("Nice hit. Enemy lost " + decreaseHealth2)

      hit()
    } else if (playerHealthFight <= 0) {
      console.log("Damn, you lost. ")
    } else if (enemyHealth <= 0) {
      console.log("Yayyyyy, YOU WONNN !!! ")
    }
  }

  hit()
```

Thanks for all the help !

Answer (score 0):

Did you try recursion? Something like this.

```
let playerHealth = 5;

let enemyHealth = 5;

function randomDecreaseHealth() {
  return Math.random()
}

function headerColor(shape, color1, color2, round) {
console.log(`${shape}: ${round}`)
}

let colors = {
  blue: "blue",
  green: "green"
}



let count = 0;

function hit() {
  if (playerHealth > 0 || enemyHealth > 0) {
    
    count++

    headerColor("ROUND", colors.blue, colors.green, count)

    let decreaseHealth1 = randomDecreaseHealth()
    playerHealth = playerHealth - decreaseHealth1
    console.log("Ouch ! You lost " + decreaseHealth1)

    let decreaseHealth2 = randomDecreaseHealth()
    enemyHealth = enemyHealth - decreaseHealth2
    console.log("Nice hit. Enemy lost " + decreaseHealth1)
    
    hit()
  } else if (playerHealth <= 0) {
    console.log("Damn, you lost.  ")
  } else if (enemyHealth <= 0) {
    console.log("Yayyyyy, YOU WONNN !!! ")
  }
}


hit()
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me, it returns _TypeError: Assignment to constant variable_ error and I can't find that alleged constant variable.

Comment: @Veljko03 Are you using TypeScript? Here's a JS fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/016Lft9g/3/